# Having a nested ViewModel and want to bubble up a command to the owning viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application with a workarea that resembles a file system on a computer. I have a ViewModel that holds the top folder and a list of subfolders:

```
public interface IRepositoryViewModel : IViewModelBase
    {
        ObservableCollection<IRepositoryTreeFolderModel> RootFolders { get; set; }         
    }
```

The IRepositoryTreeFolderModel is described like this:

```
public interface IRepositoryTreeFolderModel : IViewModelBase
    {        
        Folder Folder { get; set; }
        ObservableCollection<IRepositoryTreeFolderModel> SubFolders { get; set; }  
        bool IsSelected {get;set;}
        bool IsExpanded {get;set;}
    }
```

Please note that this is "recursive" with the same viewmodel nested. The purpose of this is to represent a tree structure of folders. I represent the data structure using a treeview, everything is working perfect. Now i need to have my "outer" IRepositoryViewModel know when i select a Folder in the tree. This is where i think im missing something. What im trying to do is to make a RoutedCommand, and consume it in my outer "IRepositoryViewModel"

```
My XAML for the treeView in the workarea is like this:

 <TreeView Background="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding RootFolders}" >   
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubFolders}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/GWManagerAdmin;component/Graphics/Navigation/folder.png" Stretch="None" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Folder.Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>                    
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

Do i need to raise my RoutedEvent in my IsSelected implementation manually (how to do this?) or is there a better approach for doing this. The problem here is that i do now know which instance of the IRepositoryTreeFolderModel has been selected, so i cant wire up a classic eventhandler and propagate it up - would also like to utilize the full potential of the RoutedCommand - i feel this is what I should do in this scenario...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Dan Wahlin's [DataContext Proxy](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just some idea from me. First you can read this http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2009/05/mvvm-invoking-command-on-attached-event.html to build up yours.

In XAML, you can invoke command from parent by this snippet:

```
Command={Binding RelativeResource={RelativeResource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}, Path=DataContext.YourCommand}
CommandArgument={Binding}
```

Hope it helps. I have not implemented myself. Just an idea.